# Click delete box to delete box and text using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a shopping list, and next to each item there is a delete button. I want to click the button and remove the button and text next to it using javascript. I have tried the following but I have not had luck. I grabbed each button using document.getElementsByClassName("delete");, then added a click event to each using a for loop. I then created the remove function seen in the code that should delete the whole element on a click. Thanks.

html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
    <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <ul>
        <li class="italic" random="23">Notebook <button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
        <li class="bold red">Jelly <button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
        <li>Spinach <button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
        <li>Rice <button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
        <li>Birthday cake <button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
        <li>Candles <button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var del = document.getElementsByClassName("delete");

function inputLength() {
    return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";
}

function addListAfterClick() {
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
    if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

function onOffClick(event) {
    this.classList.toggle("done");
}

function remove(event) {
    event.target.remove();
}

for (var i=0; i<li.length; i++) {
    li[i].addEventListener("click", onOffClick);
}

for(var i = 0; i < del.length; i++){
    del[i].addEventListener("click", remove);
}


button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);

input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);
```

Answer (score 2):

your using `event.target` to remove the element. The problem is that `event.target` only targets the button and not the link. try using `event.target.parentElement`